# Rsync from Windows10 to Mac does not allow multiple source paths

Tags: macos, rsync

I used to run a nightly rsync client on a Raspberry Pi to backup some folders from a Windows 10 computer. This script has been running without an issue for more than 10 years. I've recently moved the client from the Pi to an older Mac running High Sierra. The backup script is fairly elaborate, but I've narrowed my problem down to this on the Mac: If I have more than one source directory (a path on the Windows10 PC), the rsync command fails. If I have just one source directory, the command works. It doesn't matter what the source directories are. Any single one of them as a source directory works fine. Two or more fails. This exact same rsync command line works on the Raspberry Pi, and used to work on Ubuntu.

This command works, backing up some music from PC to Mac:

```
rsync -azv -e /usr/bin/ssh --progress --delete --exclude tbird.bkup --exclude .DS_Store --link-dest=/Volumes/backups/ronopolis/5_thu \
    rsync_user@ronopolis:/cygdrive/d/Music /Volumes/backups/ronopolis/6_fri
```

This command works, backing up some DVDs:

```
rsync -azv -e /usr/bin/ssh --progress --delete --exclude tbird.bkup --exclude .DS_Store --link-dest=/Volumes/backups/ronopolis/5_thu \
    rsync_user@ronopolis:/cygdrive/d/DVD  /Volumes/backups/ronopolis/6_fri
```

This *fails*, because I have two source paths:

```
rsync -azv -e /usr/bin/ssh --progress --delete --exclude tbird.bkup --exclude .DS_Store --link-dest=/Volumes/backups/ronopolis/5_thu \
    rsync_user@ronopolis:/cygdrive/d/DVD rsync_user@ronopolis:/cygdrive/d/Music  /Volumes/backups/ronopolis/6_fri
```

This is the error message:

```
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.0.1/rsync/main.c(1170) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

Comment: I didn't even know you COULD do multiple source paths in rsync.  I do similar backups on my Mac (to external drives) using rsync.  My script just uses a loop with a "hash" of key-value pairs (source and dest dirs).  Maybe give that a try, shouldn't be too much of a rewrite, and given how fast rsync is, you shouldn't really notice any performance difference (the file copies are the slow part, not the file compares, at least for me).

Comment: Yeah, my current plan is just to run an rsync cmd for each path. If you look at the man page, you can see you can have multiple sources. Really frustrating, I've never seen multiple sources not work.

rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST

Answer (score 0):

In the Mac OSX version of `rsync` (version `2.6.9`) only a single remote host and path is permitted. In version `3.0.0` an [enhancement](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#3.0.0) was included to permit multiple remote sources:

> Rsync now allows multiple remote-source args to be specified rather than having to rely on a special space-splitting side-effect of the remote- shell. Additional remote args must specify the same host or an empty one (e.g. empty: :file1 or ::module/file2). For example, this means that local use of brace expansion now works: rsync ‑av host:dir/{f1,f2} .

Usefully though, this reminds me how it's possible to use the single remote source definition to copy both your directory trees while still running the older version of `rsync`:

```
rsync -azv -e /usr/bin/ssh --progress --delete --exclude tbird.bkup --exclude .DS_Store --link-dest=/Volumes/backups/ronopolis/5_thu \
    rsync_user@ronopolis:'/cygdrive/d/DVD /cygdrive/d/Music' /Volumes/backups/ronopolis/6_fri
```